# Parse query.whereEqualTo String issue

Tags: android, jquery, string, parse-platform, objectid

I am using Parse backend for my android app. I need to query the database for a record that has a field with a specific string value. following is the Parse code

strObjectId is a String initialised with a Parse ObjectId as follows

```
        String strObjectId = MyParseObject.getObjectId();
```

Parse code

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyDataTable");
        query.whereEqualTo("code", Code);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
        {
          public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)
          {
            if (object == null) 
            {
                return;
            } 
            else 
            {
                ShowToast("Record found!");
            }
          }
        });
```

The problem is that it works perfectly okay when 'Code' is hardcoded as follows prior to running above query

```
        String Code = "krErZgz9Is";
```

But it DOES NOT work when Code is assigned Parse ObjectId as follows

```
        String Code = strObjectId;
```

Obviously the Data Table does have a record with 'code' field with value 'krErZgz9Is'

Your help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try and log the Exception if any and see what it says `if (e!=null) Log.e("ParseQuery", e.getMessage(), e);`. Also, if MyParseObject is not saved to Parse yet, it will not have an objectId. Finally, if you have the MyParseObject pointer, you can do `query.whereEqualTo("code", MyParseObject );`, that is, if the column called `code` is of type pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print out the strObjectId? If your object is not yet saved in Parse, or the object is not loaded from Parse. It will not have an object Id.

Also, have you tried to check the equality with the objectId directly?

```
query.whereEqualTo("code", MyParseObject.getObjectId());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working for me

I created an EditText and contained the text I want to find a match in my query. Just try to hide it in the layout if you don't really want to show it.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

editText.setText(strObjectId);


ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyDataTable");
query.whereEqualTo("code", editText.getText().toString());
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
{
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)
    {
        if (object == null) 
        {
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            ShowToast("Record found!");
        }
    }
});
```

I don't get it why removing the getText() function doesn't work so you better keep it this way.